# How do I detect which push notification device a user currently using?

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification, service-worker, user-experience

I would like to show a list of devices that a user has enabled push notifications for in their dashboard. In this list I would like to highlight the current device they are using if it's in the list or show a "Add this device" button if it's not in the list. So let's say the user has enabled push notifications on their phone and on their desktop. They log into the dashboard on their phone. Is there a way for me to tell that it's their phone? Also, what if they decide to block notifications in their browser or do a factory reset (my database won't sync obviously)? So what would be a good way to purge that old device from the list?

I'm doing this because I want a good user experience and I want to give users the option to toggle push notifications on/off per device through the dashboard without making them do it through the browser which could end up in them never re-enabling them again.

I was thinking maybe passing a hardcoded (but generated) id variable into the service worker?

`let deviceId = 0;`

But this seems really clunky. Is there a better way?

PS. My backend is PHP and MYSQL. Don't think it matters, but any answers with server-side code I'd prefer with those. I think this is all client-side though.

Comment: Could you just detect the user agent, and record a flag for each of those, per user account?

Comment: I was thinking that, but the issue is there's no guarantee that the user agent won't change if the browser is updated. So ultimately I think I'm going to go with the local web storage.

Answer (score 2):

If the user resets the browser (device), you will only discover it by trying to send something and getting a 404. So it's not possible to always be able to show a list of devices with 100 % correct info if you're not spamming the user all the time. You could probably show something like the last time a push was delivered to a certain device, maybe that would be good UX-wise.

To detect which of the devices is the current one looking at the list, simply use some sort of an id that is saved in the db when the push subscription is created. Then hold on to that id in the device (browser) and based on that, make one of the items on the list pop up.

Comment: To your second point, maybe web storage would work. It'd be nice if there was a way to ping an endpoint to see if it's still active without sending a push notification. Maybe there is and I'm just not aware of it.